# Drop down list from database sort order alphanumeric

Tags: php, sql

I am using some php to populate a dropdown list from my database. But I cant seem to figure out how to get the sort order of the list alphanumeric.

Here is my code. Its probably a bit of a mess im not a coder im only learning the ropes now, so please take it easy on me.

```
<label>Category:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="channel_category" id='category_name' 
               Placeholder="Category" onchange="show_category()">

<?php
    $qry="select * from category where parent_cat IS NOT NULL order by 
          category_id ASC";

    $res=mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['category_name'] ?>">
    <?php echo $row['category_name'] ?>
</option>
<?php 
    } 
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the query you're using to get the data for this list, you have explicitly told it to sort the data by `category_id` with this:

```
order by category_id ASC
```

If you want it to be sorted by `category_name` instead, change it to

```
order by category_name
```

`ASC` is the default sort direction and can be omitted. You can check [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) for more details on `ORDER BY`.